# Почему конец строки даёт два матча (совпадения)? findall('.*$', 'a') = ['a', '']

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения

Выполняю:

```
from re import *
print(findall('.*a', ',a'))
print(findall('.*$', ',a'))
```

Результат:

```
[',a']
[',a', '']
```

Во втором случае добавлен ещё один результат. Почему так происходит?

Comment: Всё верно. 1) находит всю строку, 2) конец строки. Так работают почти все регулярные выражения.Добавьте `^` в начало выражения, а ещё лучше вместо `*` использовать `+`. Правда, зачем вообще тогда использовать `re.findall`, если нет `re.M`?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew То есть, конец строки всегда рассматривается как дополнительная сущность, по которой производится поиск?

Comment: Нет, просто ваше выражение возвращает пустые совпадения.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если коротко: оригинальное выражение находит 0 и более символов, отличных от символов перевода строки, после которого проверяет текущую позицию на конец строки, но сам конец строки остаётся непройденным, индекс всё ещё перед концом строки. Так как в начале выражения нет проверки на начало строки (`^`), [*`re.findall`*](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.findall) имеет право (что и делает) находит следующее совпадение  - конец строки, который и возвращает.

Посмотрим, что примерно происходит.

[Выражение `.*a`](https://regex101.com/r/ACHlZ4/1/debugger) находит 0 и более символов кроме символов перевода строки (т.е. до конца строки), потом начинается "обратный отсчет", backtracking. `a` находит `a` в конце строки, `,a` возвращается как первое совпадение. Второго нет, так как нет второго `a` после найденного первого совпадения.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[Второе выражение `.*$`](https://regex101.com/r/1fs3K7/1/debugger) находит 0 и более символов кроме символов перевода строки (т.е. до конца строки) и проверяет, есть ли после захаченных символов конец строки. Да, значит, возвращает всю строку, `,a`. Однако индекс всё ещё находится перед концом строки (остался "несъеденным"). Так как `.*` может вернуть пустое совпадение, его движок и возвращает в качестве второго совпадения. Тут уже конец строки пройден ("съеден", *consumed*).

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]